# talent or talents?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

In the sentence below,

> Tucker's talent in chess and weight lifting, two of our school's most popular teams, proves his mental and physical strength.

shouldn't it be "talents", not "talent", since Tucker is good at two different things (chess & weight lifting)? Or is this way of saying acceptable?

Comment: "Talent" is a natural aptitude or skill. One does not become a weight-lifter nor chess player without a great deal of work, so "skills" (plural) might be a better choice.

Answer (score 3):

I'd prefer the plural, "talents", especially since chess and weight lifting are very different things and so presumably need very different talents. (Unless perhaps it's chess using 6' chess pieces made from depleted uranium...but even there I still prefer "talents" over "talent") Note that if the plural is used, then "proves" must become "prove".

However, I can't convince myself that the singular "talent" is simply wrong. Similar phrases come to mind and I don't think they are too offensive, for example:

> John's tendency [*not tendencies*] to eat cheesecake and talk in a loud voice makes him unsuitable for membership of the *International Quiet Cheesecake Eating Appreciation Society*.

and

> Trump's propensity [*not propensities*] for Tweeting in all-caps and holding up his right hand for emphasis means that he is grateful the *Caps Lock* key is on the left side of his keyboard.

That said, it could be argued that if we're going to insist on the singular form then in order to show that it is a singular form *being used twice in succession* they might be better written as follows (changes in bold):

> John's tendency to eat cheesecake and **to** talk in a loud voice makes him unsuitable for membership of the *International Quiet Cheesecake Eating Appreciation Society*.

and

> Trump's propensity for Tweeting in all-caps and **for** holding up his right hand for emphasis means that he is grateful the *Caps Lock* key is on the left side of his keyboard.

Comment: If we do change "talent" into "talents" (and also "proves" to "prove"), should I also change "strength" to "strengths"?